# Updating arrays in an array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to update an array but the array contains arrays.

For a example,

```
$data = array(
    array('name'=>'John','age'=>'19','alive'=>'false'),
    array('name'=>'Bob','age'=>'32','alive'=>'false'),  
    array('name'=>'Kate','age'=>'22','alive'=>'false'), 

);
```

I need to add another element to all these arrays.

I tried using foreach

```
foreach($data as $onearray){
     $onearray['alive'] = 'true';
}
```

Do I need to create a new array and add all updated arrays back to new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the referencing:

```
foreach($data as &$onearray) {
     $onearray['alive'] = 'true';
}
unset($onearray)
```

and clean up the reference afterwards, so further code will not mess it up

---

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
> precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
> reference.

see foreach-reference for more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 7):

Did you try using the data array key? Like so:

```
foreach($data as $key => $onearray){
     $data[$key]['alive'] = 'true';
}
```

*( Notice the $onearray never gets used )*

Even faster would be:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $data[$i]['alive'] = 'true';
}
```

Comment: Even faster would be `for($i = 0; $c = count($data); $i < $c; $i++) {`, but the time difference will be very small anyway, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The gain is not much. However, it's good to try and accustom to using a for loop when foreach is not necessary ( because foreach runs on a 'copy' of the array, thus using up more memory )

Comment: Sry, but this solution is VERY POOR.
uses hashmap-lookups all the time. use array_walk or references instead to get the code runing in a good time.

you should **NOT USE THIS EXAMPLE**

Comment: I did a small benchmark with four different methods posted here (1000000 iterations) and it turns out passing by references is the fastest and the solution provided in the second part of this answer is the slowest. See the results [here](http://goo.gl/BBjcrS).

Comment: Then I stand corrected, and have learned! Thanks. I would like to add that for a novice programmer using references might be harder to understand ( although this example is easy enough ), especially if one forgets to unset the last reference and uses the variable later on. Don't you think? 

Also *very poor* might not be the best way to describe my answer, a bit harsh, no?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in function [array_walk](https://www.php.net/array_walk) — Apply a user function to every member of an array

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

Output

```
Before ...:
d. lemon
a. orange
b. banana
c. apple
... and after:
d. fruit: lemon
a. fruit: orange
b. fruit: banana
c. fruit: apple
```